# How do you make a shell function that you can pipe into to make the output red?

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh

I want something where I can do `{some command} | red` and it'll output whatever `{some command}` would have outputted, but red. The best I've been able to do is

```
function red()
{
    while read text
    do
        echo -e '\033[31m'$text'\033[0m'
    done
}
```

But this removes all the indentation.

This seems like something that should be easy but I just can't seem to figure it out. I was trying to do it just for fun but now I just need to know, 'cause there has to be a simple way to do this that I'm missing.

EDIT:

I've also tried this in C like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* buffer = malloc(8);
    int size     = 8;
    int index    = 0;

    while ((buffer[index++] = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (index == size)
        {
            size *= 2;
            buffer = realloc(buffer, size);
        }
    }
    buffer[index] = 0;

    printf("%s%s%s", "\\033[31m", buffer, "\\033[0m");
}
```

But the shell doesn't interpret the escape characters, and so doesn't make the output red.

Comment: `red() { echo -e '\033[31m'; cat; echo -e '\033[0m'; }`?

Comment: That worked! I've never seen ```cat``` used that way, I didn't know it could do that!

Comment: Please no `echo -e`. `red(){ printf '\e[31m';cat;printf '\e[0m';}`. Also @thsutton solution inserts leading and trailing newlines before and after the text output from `cat`.

Comment: @LéaGris : Of course `printf` is preferable, but wrt to the newlines,we could get rid of them by using `echo -en`, I think.

Comment: An option in `zsh` is to use `print -P`. Then you can avoid the hard-coded terminal escape sequences: `red() {print -nP %F{red}; cat; print -nP %f}`.

Comment: @Jack : Why is this tagged _bash_ **and** _zsh_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was only missing a couple things for it to work:

- Firstly you want to neutralize the **I**nternal **F**ield **S**eparator `IFS` environment variable, because it was the cause of your discarded indentation. This variable caused the read operation to eat leading tabs and spaces as field separator.
- Next you wan to `read -r`. The `-r` flag prevent the interpretation of escaped characters and have a **r**aw read instead.
- Finally, you must not use `echo -e`. It is a horrible non-standard way of printing `\` escaped characters. Use a `printf` instead.
- Additionally, the loop on the `read` will not handle the last line of text if it does not contain an newline character `\n`. The shell  `read` returns `false` in this case after reading the remaining text, and break out of the `while` loop without processing the last line not ending with a newline.
  It is dealt with testing if the `line` contains a last line of text and print it without a newline for this special last case.

Now here it is all fixed and working as you intended to:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function red() {
  while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf '\e[31m%s\e[0m\n' "$line"
  done
  [ -n "$line" ] && printf '\e[31m%s\e[0m' "$line"
}

red
```

**EDIT:**

As [@Thsutton commented above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294233/how-do-you-make-a-shell-function-that-you-can-pipe-into-to-make-the-output-red/69294456#comment122475327_69294233), you can use `cat` in the `red` function to insert the ANSI CSI sequences before and after the whole text only, rather than for each line of text. It does not need a while loop, so will undoubtedly be more performant. Although note that the per-line method might give better results if the text stream itself contains ANSI CSI sequences changing the terminal colour.

```sh
red() {
  printf '\e[31m'
  cat
  printf '\e[0m'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing the escape codes explicitly is IMO cumbersome. I would do something like

```
red() {
  # Send stdin to stdout, but coloured in red, if the
  # terminal supports it.
  if tput setaf 196 2>/dev/null
  then
    cat
    tput sgr0 # reset the attribute
  else
    # No support for changing the colour. Just display it
    # using the default foreground colour
    cat
  fi
}
```

which also works on terminals which are not configured for color.

The magical number *196* comes from [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) table.